# 2 row swipe menu android native JAVA

Tags: java, android, xml, swipe, communication

[image]

I am confused about this design.
I am working on an Android application and the main tech is swipe 2-row menu.

> Left-to-Right ||| before page
>
> Right-to-Left ||| next page

This activity is reflected to indicate dots.

I tried with VerticalScrollview and Recyclerview. But it doesn't work for me.
If you have any ideas, please share.

Answer (score 0):

> **Control several page with Viewpager !**

> Please add this .xml

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
             android:id="@+id/dash_pager"
             android:layout_width="247.5dp"
             android:layout_height="175dp"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

> setAdapter in Activity or fragment:

```
final ViewPager viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.dash_pager);
final DashPagerAdapter adapter = new DashPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> Adapter

```
public class DashPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    /**
     * Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
     *
     * @param position
     */
    int mNoOfTabs;
    public DashPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Landing_one tab1 =new Landing_one();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Landing_two tab2 = new Landing_two();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return  null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of views available.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

Make 2 fragment Landing_one and Landing_two.